# Use only specific Objects of a List regarding their value

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I use flutter_map library and I have an array of objects that I named POIs (point of interest) which are displayed on a map. Every poi has a value named type which can be "map_eglise", "map_basilique", etc... All of them are displayed on my map and it causes a lot of lags when ther is many pois displayed.

I want to display only a certain type of poi regarding the zoom level on the map. I know how to get the zoom level (in my `mapController.zoom`) but I don't know how to filter my `pois` array and objects with the zoom level. I've written a function named `getFiltersByZoom` which I think could be useful, but I didn't find a way to use it at the moment.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            center: LatLng(43.69653967432033, 7.27036144753221),
            zoom: 15.0,
            minZoom: 4.0,
            maxZoom: 18.0,
            interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.all & ~InteractiveFlag.rotate,
          ),
          mapController: mapController,
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
                subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            ),
            MarkerLayerOptions(
              markers: [
                for (var poi in pois)...[
                  Marker(
                    point: LatLng(double.parse(poi.latitude), double.parse(poi.longitude)),
                    builder: (context) => Image.asset('assets/markers/pin_${poi.type}.png'),
                  ),
                ]
              ]//markers
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
```

```
List<String> getFiltersByZoom(zoom) {
  switch (zoom) {
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
      return ["map_basilique", "map_cathedrale"];
    case 9:
    case 10:
      return ["map_basilique", "map_cathedrale", "special_paroisse"];
    case 11:
      return ["map_basilique", "map_cathedrale", "special_paroisse", "map_eglise"];
    default:
      return ["detail_art", "map_basilique", "map_cathedrale", "map_chapelle", "map_eglise", "map_hotel", "map_monastere", "map_oratoire", "map_sanctuaire", "special_paroisse"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your marker layer options

```dart
MarkerLayerOptions(
              markers: [
                for (var poi in pois)...[
                  Marker(
                    point: LatLng(double.parse(poi.latitude), double.parse(poi.longitude)),
                    builder: (context) => Image.asset('assets/markers/pin_${poi.type}.png'),
                  ),
                ]
              ]
            ),
```

Like this:

```dart
MarkerLayerOptions(markers: filteredMarkers(zoom.toInt(), pois)),
```

Here is the function to implement:

```dart
List<Marker> filteredMarkers(int zoom, List<Poi> pois) {
List<Marker> markers = [];
List<String> filtered = getFiltersByZoom(zoom);

pois.forEach((poi) {
  if (filtered.contains(poi.type)) {
      markers.add(
        Marker(
          point: LatLng(double.parse(poi.latitude), double.parse(poi.longitude)),
          builder: (context) => Image.asset('assets/markers/pin_${poi.type}.png'),
        ),
      );
  }
});
return markers;
```